# how to log original arguments before shrink in scalacheck

Tags: scalacheck

When I use Shrink in my scalacheck test, scalacheck only print arguments after shrink that failed my test case. Is there any way to make scalacheck also print the original arguments before shrink? Thanks!

Comment: I think in most cases you would fix the test case for the shrunk arguments and then run it again. This will either fix the more complicated case, or the more complicated case will not be able to be shrunk and those arguments will be printed. Is there a reason that this workflow doesn't work for you?

Comment: The problem is: I wrote a custom Shrink and wanna check if it works properly

Comment: This is how ScalaCheck shrinking works, now.  It produces both the failing value and the original shrunk value.